# Porting JS/TS function to MySQL — Large Integers

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript

**TL/DR**: What logic can I add to `SELECT (-1816598198 << 8);` to ensure that it returns `-1192670720` like in JS/TS?

**Full Question**:

I'm having trouble porting a JS/TS function to MySQL. The function I have is:

```
const BuildIDLookupTable = [0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, /* ... */ 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4];

function getBuildId(gPsyonixBuildId: string): number {
  let result = -1;

  for (const character of gPsyonixBuildId) {
    const charCode = character.charCodeAt(0);

    result = BuildIDLookupTable[(result >>> 24) ^ (charCode & 0xff)] ^ (result << 8);
    result = BuildIDLookupTable[(result >>> 24) ^ (charCode >>> 8)] ^ (result << 8);
  }

  return ~result;
}
```

I created a MySQL table, `build_id_lookup`, and inserted the proper values. I've got the MySQL function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`stev`@`%` FUNCTION `getBuildId`(gPsyonixBuildId VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS bigint
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE characterCode INT;
    DECLARE characterIndex INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE gPsyonixBuildIdLength INT DEFAULT CHAR_LENGTH(gPsyonixBuildId);
    DECLARE result BIGINT DEFAULT -1;

    WHILE characterIndex < gPsyonixBuildIdLength DO
        SET characterCode = ASCII(SUBSTRING(gPsyonixBuildId, characterIndex, 1));
        
        SELECT CAST(`value` ^ (result << 8) AS SIGNED) INTO result FROM `build_id_lookup` WHERE `index` = result >> 24 & 0xff ^ (characterCode & 0xff);
        
        -- The (result << 8) yields unexpected results in comparison to JS/TS.
        SELECT CAST(`value` ^ (result << 8) AS SIGNED) INTO result FROM `build_id_lookup` WHERE `index` = result >> 24 & 0xff ^ (characterCode >> 8 & 0xff);
        
        SET characterIndex = characterIndex + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN ~result;
END
```

I'm finding that MySQL's `(result << 0x8)` is giving different results than JS/TS.

For example, `SELECT (-1816598198 << 8);` yields `18446743608660412928` in MySQL, but yields `-1192670720` in JS/TS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
-- convert to binary string
SELECT BIN(-1816598198) step1; 
-- shift then convert to binary string
SELECT BIN(-1816598198 << 8) step2;
-- cut off excess bits
SELECT RIGHT(BIN(-1816598198 << 8), 32) step3;
-- convert to decimal value
SELECT CONV(RIGHT(BIN(-1816598198 << 8), 32), 2, 10) step4;
-- adjust due to 1st bit is 1 (negative output)
SELECT CONV(RIGHT(BIN(-1816598198 << 8), 32), 2, 10) - 4294967296 step5;
```

| step1 |
| --- |
| 1111111111111111111111111111111110010011101110001110100101001010 |

| step2 |
| --- |
| 1111111111111111111111111001001110111000111010010100101000000000 |

| step3 |
| --- |
| 10111000111010010100101000000000 |

| step4 |
| --- |
| 3102296576 |

| step5 |
| --- |
| -1192670720 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lL3seVNO)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a basic MySQL function to simulate overflow:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`stev`@`%` FUNCTION `simulateOverflow`(number DECIMAL(65, 0)) RETURNS int
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE largeNumber DECIMAL(65, 0) DEFAULT 4294967296;
  DECLARE maxInt DECIMAL(65, 0) DEFAULT 2147483647;
  DECLARE minInt DECIMAL(65, 0) DEFAULT -2147483648;
  DECLARE result INT;

  IF number > maxInt THEN
    SET result = number - FLOOR((number + maxInt + 2) / largeNumber) * largeNumber;
  ELSEIF number < minInt THEN
    SET result = number + FLOOR((number - minInt) / largeNumber) * -largeNumber;
  END IF;

  RETURN result;
END
```

Which was just a port of my JS/TS function for doing the same:

```
export function overflow(number: bigint): bigint;
export function overflow(number: number): number;
export function overflow(number: bigint | number): bigint | number {
  if (number > 2_147_483_647) {
    if (typeof number === 'bigint') {
      return number - ~~((number + 2_147_483_649n) / 4_294_967_296n) * 4_294_967_296n;
    }

    return number - ~~((number + 2_147_483_649) / 4_294_967_296) * 4_294_967_296;
  } else if (number < -2_147_483_648) {
    if (typeof number === 'bigint') {
      return number + ~~((number - 2_147_483_648n) / 4_294_967_296n) * -4_294_967_296n;
    }

    return number + ~~((number - 2_147_483_648) / 4_294_967_296) * -4_294_967_296;
  }

  return number;
}
```